# Uncaught (In Promise) error while using setTimeout() to Reject a promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, asynchronous, es6-promise

I am learning promises in javascript and I decided to implement a simple promise where I would set a timeout of 3 seconds and then reject the promise. Upon rejecting it, I am catching the error and displaying it in an HTML element. The promise works perfectly and displays the message, but I get the following error in the console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) I hate you
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous)
```

Here is the code for your reference -

```js
const myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, reject) {
setTimeout(() => {
    reject('I hate you');
}, 3000);
});

myPromise.then(function(value) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
});

myPromise.catch( error => {
    console.log("Catching it");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = error;
});
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Promise</h2>
<p>Wait 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) for this page to change.</p>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Please help me in finding out the error that I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPromise.then(function(value) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
}).catch( error => {
    console.log("Catching it");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = error;
});
```

You need to catch the error after .then

Comment: Why does it not work if I define them like I did the original post? Is it mandatory to chain the 'then' and 'catch' together?

Comment: @SatyamRai The goal of promise is to chain multiple then/catch. 'Then' returns a new Promise that you should use to catch an eventual error. Your code works but it is bad because you are not catching an eventual error on the first .then.  For further information/details : https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```html
<html>

<body>

  <h2>JavaScript Promise</h2>

  <p>Wait 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) for this page to change.</p>

  <h1 id="demo"></h1>

  <script>
    const myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        reject('I hate you');
      }, 3000);
    });

    myPromise.then(function(value) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Catching it");
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = error;
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the comment by **tlvi38** on the accepted answer, I understand my query now, and the uncaught issue from the original question posted by the OP can be fixed by adding a separate `catch` block for the new promise returned by the unchained `then` as following:

```js
const myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject("I hate you");
  }, 500);
});

const newUncaughtPromise = myPromise.then(function (value) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
});

myPromise.catch((error) => {
  console.log("Catching it");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = error;
});

newUncaughtPromise.catch((error) => {
  console.log("Catching the uncaught it");
  document.getElementById("demo_uncaught").innerHTML = error;
});
```

**ORIGINAL**
Since I cannot add a comment, I am writing this as an answer, but I observed that other than the accepted answer, if you have just the `catch` block like following, it also works without any issue.

```js
const myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject('I hate you');
  }, 3000);
});
  
myPromise.catch( error => {
  console.log("Catching it");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = error;
});
```

But having both, `then` and `catch` not chained up, in any order gives `Uncaught error..` in console. Can someone explain why is that?

Comment: If you have a .then without a catch and this promise rejects, javascript will throw an error because you did not catch the error. Assigning the result of .then into a new variable, and then adding .catch onto this variable after, is exactly the same as chaining... It is just a bit more confusing.   Moreover, you are catching the same error two times in your code. 'myPromise.catch((error) => {
  console.log("Catching it");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = error;
});' is useless. You are basically listening twice the same result.